# postfix empty from when redirecting to return-path

Tags: postfix

We are sending mail from our server via postfix, and capturing bounces in an inbox via return-path. We're seeing an odd situation where sometimes the bounce rejection appears to happen directly during the sending process, in which case (it seems) our server is then acting as a relay to pass along the bounce to the bounce inbox. That's fine -- except that outgoing email fails because no FROM address is set.

So I think we just need guidance setting a default FROM address in postfix. But I don't know for certain if that's the case. Here's the redacted mail server logs:

```
Feb 15 23:58:31 mydomain postfix/pickup[16622]: B469C261093: uid=33 from=<bounces@mydomain.info>
Feb 15 23:58:31 mydomain postfix/cleanup[21945]: B469C261093: message-id=<m.584.169.a4131afc7d377d8e@mydomain.info>
Feb 15 23:58:31 mydomain postfix/qmgr[15254]: B469C261093: from=<bounces@mydomain.info>, size=62845, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 15 23:58:31 mydomain postfix/smtp[21947]: B469C261093: to=<badaddress@somedomain.com>, relay=aspmx.l.google.com[xx.xx.xx.xx]:25, delay=0.07, delays=0.01/0/0.04/0.02, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (host aspmx.l.google.com[xx.xx.xx.xx] said: 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try 550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or 550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at 550 5.1.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6596 81si37032134qhz.3 - gsmtp (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Feb 15 23:58:31 mydomain postfix/cleanup[21945]: C752826109A: message-id=<20160215235831.C752826109A@www.mydomain.info>
Feb 15 23:58:31 mydomain postfix/bounce[21948]: B469C261093: sender non-delivery notification: C752826109A
Feb 15 23:58:31 mydomain postfix/qmgr[15254]: C752826109A: from=<>, size=3121, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 15 23:58:31 mydomain postfix/qmgr[15254]: B469C261093: removed
Feb 15 23:58:37 mydomain postfix/smtp[21947]: C752826109A: host mail.mydomain.info[xx.xx.xx.xx] said: 451 Temporary local problem - please try later (in reply to end of DATA command)
Feb 15 23:58:39 mydomain postfix/smtp[21947]: C752826109A: to=<bounces@mydomain.info>, relay=mx.something.com[xx.xx.xx.xx]:25, delay=7.5, delays=0/0/7.5/0.03, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host mx.something.com[xx.xx.xx.xx] said: 550 <> Sender rejected. (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
Feb 15 23:58:39 mydomain postfix/qmgr[15254]: C752826109A: removed
```

Can someone provide guidance on how to set the FROM address, or shed insight if that is not the actual problem?

Comment: I'm not really sure I'm even asking the right question. Maybe the question I should be asking is... why is google bouncing back to the server rather than to the return-path address?